# Why a Python subclass does not inherit its parent class's annotations?

Tags: python, python-3.x

A Python subclass does not inherit its parent class's annotations apparently:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

class A:
    valA: int
    
class B(A):
    valB: str

print(B.__annotations__)
```

Output:

```
{'valB': <class 'str'>}
```

Why is that? How can I make it so?

Comment: Well the why is that the class A and class B are different objects. Being a subclass means that objects of type B will also be an `instanceof` type A as well as type B. It does not make A and B classes themselves into objects with the same attributes.

Comment: If you do `__annotations__.update(A.__annotations__)` in `B`, it works, but IDK if that's the right way to do it.

Comment: This is *never* how inheritance works

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga It does in typed languages. The members are inherited, along with their... types...

Comment: Short answer seems to be, as always, _because Python_. This is literally how inheritance works everywhere else.

Comment: @alelom "everywhere else" doesn't necessarily **have** anything analogous to annotations in the first place. Annotations **are not** types; they have **no effect** on the runtime behaviour of the code in the reference implementation of Python, aside from providing some inspectable metadata.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel For reference: my comment was done with **clear knowledge** of Python OOP's "capabilities" and of Typing (PEP484). I also think that _metadata_ **is not** an appropriate term, as Annotations are closer to docs than to language metadata (see _metaprogramming_). PEP484 entirely pushes static type checking responsibility to the linter, which is complex for linters to implement effectively (I haven't found a linter that always reliably uses it yet). OP highlights one of the issues with this design choice: you may need hacks to get the behaviour you'd expect at runtime (see answer).

Answer (score 0):

Idea:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def updateAnnotations(annotations, bases):
    for base in bases:
        annotations.update(getattr(base, '__annotations__', dict()))

class A:
    valA: int
    
class B:
    valB: int
    
class C(A, B):
    valC: int
    
    updateAnnotations(__annotations__, [A, B])

print(sorted(C.__annotations__.items()))
```

Output:

```
[('valA', <class 'int'>), ('valB', <class 'int'>), ('valC', <class 'int'>)]
```

Using a decorator:

```
def update_annotations(cls: typing.Type) -> typing.Type:
    annotations = getattr(cls, '__annotations__', None)
    if annotations == None:
        cls.__annotations__ = dict()
        annotations = cls.__annotations__

    for clsType in [cls] + list(cls.__bases__):
        annotations.update(getattr(clsType, '__annotations__', dict()))

    return cls

class A:
    valA: int

class B:
    valA: str
    valB: int

@update_annotations    
class C(A, B):
    valC: int
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.valA = 'asd'
        self.valB = 30
        self.valC = 40

print(C.__annotations__)
```

Output:

```
{'valC': <class 'int'>, 'valA': <class 'str'>, 'valB': <class 'int'>}
```

Comment: Great! It's really disheartening how Python makes your life hard for literally everything. This is helpful. Thanks.